# Find minimum and maximum of year and month in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to find minimum of year and month and maximum of year and month from spark dataframe. Below is my dataframe

```
code  year  month 
xx    2004  1
xx    2004  2
xxx   2004  3
xx    2004  6
xx    2011  12
xx    2018  10
```

I want minimum month and Year as 2004-1 and maximum month and year as 2018-10

The solution which i tried is

```
  val minAnMaxYearAndMonth = dataSet.agg(min(Year),max(Month)).head()
val minYear = minAnMaxYearAndMonth(0)
val maxYear = minAnMaxYearAndMonth(1)
val minMonth = dataSet.select(Month).where(col(Year)  === minYear).take(1)
val maxMonth = dataSet.select(Month).where(col(Year)  === maxYear).take(1)
```

getting minYear and MaxYear but not min and max Month. Please help

Comment: your aggregation should be ```dataSet.agg(min(Year),max(Year)).head()```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`struct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#struct-org.apache.spark.sql.Column...-) to make tuples out of years and months and then rely on tuple ordering. Tuples are ordered primarily by the leftmost component and then using next component as a tie-breaker.

```
df.select(struct("year", "month") as "ym")
  .agg(min("ym") as "min", max("ym") as "max")
  .selectExpr("stack(2, 'min', min.*, 'max', max.*) as (agg, year, month)")
  .show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+-----+
|agg|year|month|
+---+----+-----+
|min|2004|    1|
|max|2018|   10|
+---+----+-----+
```